# django-raster rendering raster url

Tags: python, postgis, python-2.7, geodjango, django

i want to add raster functionality in django using postgis database using django-raster package and this [docs](http://django-raster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tms.html).

here my code :

models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class RasterWithName(models.Model):
    raster = models.RasterField()
    name = models.TextField()
```

add raster using console :

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALRaster
from myapp.models import RasterWithName
gdal_raster = GDALRaster('C:/Users/username/Desktop/image.tif')
rast = RasterWithName(name='one', raster=gdal_raster)
rast.save()
```

but i am very confused with Rendering tiles and urls.

docs say :

> /raster/tiles/layer_id/{z}/{x}/{y}.png where the layer_id is the
>   primary key of a raster layer. This structure can be used directly in
>   online mapping software such as OpenLayers or Leaflet. An example
>   request could look like this: /raster/tiles/23/8/536/143.png,
>   returning a tile in png format of the layer with ID pk=23 at zoom
>   level z=8 and indexes x=536 and y=143

but indexes x,y mean some random x,y coordinate in image ?anyway i using this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/raster/tiles/1/8/536/143.png` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/raster/tiles/1/8/20/40.png`(origin x,y in my image) and i take a black window in my browser,any idea where i have wrong in my url rendering ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code example you create your own raster model. That is not compatible with the functionality of the django-raster package. The goal of django-raster is to avoid having to create and manage raster models.

To use it, first make sure django-raster is correctly installed, see https://django-raster.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html).

Then the raster files itself should be stored using the RasterLayer model that comes with the django-raster package. The easiest way to add your image is to use the django admin site. Simply create a new RasterLayer in the admin and upload your file using the rasterfile field.

So to display your raster data you don't need to write (much) code, just configure django-raster in your Django project and start using its functionality (such as ingesting and displaying raster data).